# I can connect to my SSH server but cannot browse the internet

Tags: macos, networking, ssh, proxy, port-forwarding

I have setup an ssh server on my windows 8.1 system as well as port forwarding on my home router and from inside and outside of the network I can login on my macbook using the command `ssh -D 8080 user@X.X.X.X -p 443`(in the actuall command the X's are my public ip address). Once I've logged in I activate the socks proxy 127.0.0.1:8080. I know that I have successfully logged in because I can view my home computer's entire folder structure. Now here is where I get confused; although I am successfully logged in and have properly setup my socks proxy my browser times out when i attempt to go to any web pages and never takes me there.

I have tried:

- Using ports other than 8080(which gives me an error and immediately closes the ssh connection when I try to go to a webpage)
- Logging in from different networks including internally on my home network
- Using multiple browsers
- Turning the firewall off on my macbook.
- Turing the firewall off on my desktop

I'm out of ideas and have no clue what to do to get it to actually work. It is pointless for me to only be able to manipulate my file structure as i need to be able to reach git and other resources that are blocked.

Comment: I don't understand, the ssh server is on your Windows PC and you login on your mac? Do you mean you login **from** your mac using it as a ssh client?

Comment: Is your browser set to use the proxy server? It seems you've configured the proxy to serve to 8080 but if your browser is unaware of the port then it still thinks the proxy is transparent on 80...

Comment: That Brazilian Guy - Yes that is what i mean.
Chris - Yes within firefox i went to about:config and set up a socks v5 proxy 127.0.0.1:8080